# How to set varchar to real date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field named 'Date' (believe it or not) and it is Varchar(50).  Sigh.  Anyway, I want to convert this to an actual date in another field in the same table.  I tried a few things..

```
UPDATE     TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
SET        Actual_Date = Convert(varchar(30), DATE, 23)

UPDATE     TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
SET        Actual_Date = Cast(Date As Date)
```

I keep getting errors about converting a character string into date.

This should be a pretty simple thing, I think.  How can I make this work?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What does the Date look like in the varchar field? Like 2018-06-15 or something else?

Comment: This is it: '06/12/17' (without the quotes).

Comment: Are you sure all the dates are in a convertible format? Any anomalies will throw off the query.

Comment: dd/mm or mm/dd ?

Comment: '06/12/17'  is ambiguous.  June 12 or December 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CAST should work just fine.  Here is an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEST1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TEST1

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST1](
    [VALUE_VARCHAR] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [VALUE_DATE] DATE NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO TEST1 (VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES ('06/12/17')

UPDATE TEST1 SET VALUE_DATE = CAST(VALUE_VARCHAR AS DATE)

SELECT * FROM TEST1
```

[image]

You could also change the DATE column and CAST to DATETIME if you want the timestamp part.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your date (06/12/17) dd/mm/yy if so, then you can use `convert` function:

```
. . .
set Actual_Date = convert(date, '06/12/17', 3)
```

However, you can also use `cast()` .